# Flutter: Perform hittest on text

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm painting a `Paragraph` onto a `Canvas` using a `CustomPainter`. How can I find out on which pixels the text actually got painted?

Comment: you can use `PictureRecorder` to get the `Picture` and convert it to `Image` and get its byte data

Comment: What if there is already something else painted (in the same color) on the canvas?

Comment: The User is supposed to be able to draw on the Canvas using a stylus/touch, but it should also be possible to add text. I want to make it possible to erase indivdual letters, that's why I have to roughly know what's part  of the letter and what isn't.

Answer (score 0):

If its just visually, you can try visual debugging from here:
https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/debugging#visual-debugging